# Ubuntu CP210x driver failure

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel-module

When I connect CP2102 Virtual COM Port (VCP) adapter to USB I get this output:

```
[ 1893.942663] usb 1-1.1.4.2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[ 1894.052823] usb 1-1.1.4.2: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60
[ 1894.052826] usb 1-1.1.4.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1894.052828] usb 1-1.1.4.2: Product: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[ 1894.052829] usb 1-1.1.4.2: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[ 1894.052831] usb 1-1.1.4.2: SerialNumber: 0001
[ 1895.067552] cp210x: Unknown symbol usb_serial_generic_open (err 0)
[ 1895.067565] cp210x: Unknown symbol usb_serial_generic_close (err 0)
[ 1895.067579] cp210x: Unknown symbol usb_serial_deregister_drivers (err 0)
[ 1895.067595] cp210x: Unknown symbol usb_serial_register_drivers (err 0)
```

`$ lsmod | grep 210x` and `$ lsmod | grep usbserial` outputs nothing

Then I tried to rebuild the driver. Downloaded new CP210x driver form http://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers

```
$ make
$ cp ./cp210x.ko /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x.ko
$ insmod /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x.ko 
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

Also `$ modinfo usbserial` outputs

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'usbserial': No such file or directory
```

My system info: `4.8.0-58-generic #63~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:08:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

What is going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: Seems like your kernel is missing the `CONFIG_USB_SERIAL` support, which can be built into the kernel, or exist as loadable module **usbserial.ko**.

Comment: It is the case in Ubuntu 16.04.1? If yes, how then install that CP210x driver which depends on usbserial.ko?

Comment: It appears that something you did broke your kernel modules. Remove all downloaded drivers, and repair the kernel package.